No puedo ver el SAC, ni las Release Notes ni el Download Center en la página de soporte te Genexus
Hace varios días que cuando intento acceder a la página de soporte de Genexus, a los SACs, Release Notes y el Download Center, pero la página no carga.
He probado en varios PC y navegadores y en todo ocurre lo mismo, por lo que parece un error de la página.
¿Alguien sabe qué es lo que ocurre y cuando quedaría solucionado?

Si nos dijeras la URL y el error ya podríamos empezar a trabajar en ello.

Estas son las URL:
https://www.genexus.com/en/developers/websac
https://www.genexus.com/en/developers/rn
https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/downloadcenter

Websac y DownloadCenter cargan bien. La tercera (Release Notes) carga, pero tiene un control que no y que "tapa" toda la página. Si le haces scroll, puedes ver la página contenedora.

Te cargaron bien? Yo veo que carga el menú superior, pero en el cuerpo de la página no carga nada, queda en color gris.  Lo mismo ocurre con la página de Download Center.

Have varias semanas que andan con problemas. Incluso la Extranet (https://www2.genexusnet.com/gxpextranet/hgxpp001.aspx?11,1,127,O,S,0,,) tampoco funciona. Ni un aviso ni notificación oficial de parte de @Genexus

Esto no es una pregunta, es un reporte de un bug.. y no va bien con el formato de nuestro sitio.. no es algo que se pueda arreglar desde aca...

Puedes acceder al equipo de soporte por email, como se detalla en https://genexus.com/issuetracking, y pedirle links a los downloads que precises o preguntas técnicas como sucede usualmente.
Asociado a esto, y por si te sirve: La documentación técnica y principales notas respecto a liberaciones, lo puedes encontrar en https://wiki.genexus.com
